# How to emit unencoded html in the dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to populate a dropdown list with trademark and copyright characters but looks like they are always html encoded so what I get instead is their encoded form.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? How to emit "&#169;" or "&copy;" instead of ©?

Comment: I want to emit © in my dropdown list but it shows the encoded characters like &#169; The entries are stored as &#169; in the db. In other words, I want the raw output like <%= emits but from DropdownListFor helper method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When populating your SelectList, use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode on the text. Here's an example:

```
<%
var entities = new string[] { "&copy;", "&lt;&quot;&gt;", "&#169;" };
var selectListItems = entities.Select(e => new SelectListItem { 
                                    Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e), Value = "1" 
                               });
%>

<%= Html.DropDownList("exampleDropDownList", selectListItems) %>
```

Comment: How can this improve to decode text value when taking from entity generated on SQL server stored procedure, Thanks

Comment: var selectListItems = new SelectList(entities, "ID", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Text"));    This is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Or this way, if Model is SelectList

```
    @Html.DropDownList("DropDownList", Model.Select(i => { i.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(i.Text); return i; }))
```